# jQuery UI tabs not working once page loads

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have tabs setup on page load and they work perfectly. However, when I try to add more tabs dynamically, I get an error

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs'

This means that jQuery UI has suddenly gone away? Here's my code

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
function addTab(){
$('#tabs ul').append('<li><a href="#haha">HaHaHa</a></li>');
$('#tabs').append('<div id="haha">This is the new tab</div>');
$("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
</script>
<body>
   <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> 
   </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.     Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

The function "addTab()" results in error. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: What error do you get? And why isn't the addTab function closed?

Comment: Where do you call `addTab()`?

Comment: From where you are calling `addTab()`?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nAacb/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you missed a closing bracket. The following code works perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('#tabs').tabs();
            });

            function addTab(){
                $('#tabs ul').append('<li><a href="#haha">HaHaHa</a></li>');
                $('#tabs').append('<div id="haha">This is the new tab</div>');
                $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="addTab();">add tab</a>

        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">xxNunc tincidunt</a></li> 
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>
                    Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.     Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>
                    yyProin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.     Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

UPDATE: Added the "add tab" link and css.

Comment: This doesnot work. here's my code. Just added an <a> tag to trigger addTab()

Comment: @JabranSaeed, have you even tried this? Works in FF20, Chrome 27 and IE9. I added link and css so now you can just copy and paste the code to notepad and try it out. If it still doesn't work, you'll need to provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#tabs').tabs();

  $('#addTag').click(function addTab(){
    $('#tabs ul').append('<li><a href="#haha">HaHaHa</a></li>');
    $('#tabs').append('<div id="haha">This is the new tab</div>');
    $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
  });
});
```

I've created the following in which appears to work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8s3M/) im not sure if it could be how you are triggering your addTag function but I hope this helps

Comment: You are right that selection by id should be done that way, but formally both ways will work and that is certainly not the cause of OPs error.

Comment: I'm triggering the addTab() function from console, and the missing bracket is not the issue. It works fine on jsfiddle, not on my machine. I think this has to do with some other script interfering with jQuery UI. Maybe. Still no good.

Comment: What other scripts are you running? also what happens if you take the JSFiddle code directly to your machine?